# Use njs to validate JWT in Open Source nginx

Tags: nginx, njs

I would like to validate an Auth0 token inside nginx. I know that nginx plus has a way to do this but how can I do it inside custom code using njs?

Tried Googling this and looking at similar questions but I have not found a solution